# [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: python, django, date

Good day.
I have a Django views that searches items in the database. The user can search  with email or order number while filtering the database it filters for date.
If I try to search I get these as error

> [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Here is my views.py

```
def search_form(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user_search = request.GET.get('order')
        print "What is searched for is : ", user_search

        start_date = request.GET.get('first_date')
        print "The start date is : ", start_date

        end_date = request.GET.get('second_date')
        print "The end date is : ", end_date

        if user_search != None or start_date != None or end_date != None:
            items = Order.objects.filter(Q(order_number__iexact=user_search) |
                Q(client__email__iexact=user_search) |
                Q(created_on__range=[start_date, end_date])
                )
            print "items ", items
```

The error is pointing to `Q(created_on__range=[start_date, end_date])`

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Uchechukwu\Dropbox\Engrs-Shared-Projects\JSA_WEB\jsa_admin\views.py" in search_form
  926.                 Q(created_on__range=[start_date, end_date])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  790.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  808.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1243.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1263.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1269.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1203.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1099.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  57.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  746.             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1440.         value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1296.         return self.to_python(value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  1423.             params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /dashboard/search_form/
Exception Value: [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Comment: could you please include the actual traceback message?  It seems you have something trying to make a date out of an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You checked if any of the parameters are not None. But if either of start or end date are None, that check will pass, but the query will fail with the error you see. You need to check that both start and end date are not None before filtering on them.

Comment: If i query the database with date it works but if i query without date error pops out

Comment: Yes. So don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! I've set `blank=True`, but not `null=True` — fixed, solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while deploying the code on heroku.

After correcting my model attribute to

`models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,default=datetime.date.today)`

I removed all the files in migrations/* and ran the migrations on local and heroku.

`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`

That helped in fixing migration problems on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely to occur because Django expects DateTimeField values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]` format, and you probably formatted it as a string before, by using `strftime`, so that Django is not able to recognize properly which number represent a corresponding datetime variable (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timezone).

You can solve it by converting your string back to the datetime by using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior),

```
start_date = start_date.strptime(date_string, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]")
end_date = end_date.strptime(date_string, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]")
```

or you can simply remove the command

```
start_date.strftime("your_chosen_format")
end_date.strftime("your_chosen_format")
```

where you used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Had come across the same issue, and simply solved it by:

```
date = obj.date 

time = obj.time 

start_date = "%sT%s" % (date, time)
```

Answer (score -1):

use this dateformat

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
```