# django migration throws date format error

Tags: python, django

Trying to migrate using the following

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('action','ACTION'),
    ('drama','DRAMA'),
    ('comedy','COMEDY'),
    ('romance','ROMANCE'),
)

LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    ('english' , 'ENGLISH'),
    ('german' , 'GERMAN'),
)

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('RA' , 'RECRNTLY ADDED'),
    ('MW' , 'MOST WATCHED'),
    ('TR' , 'TOP RATED'),
)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies')
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies_banner')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES , max_length=10)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES , max_length=10)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES , max_length=2)
    cast = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year_of_production = models.DateField()
    views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    movie_trailer = models.URLField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self , *args , **kwargs):
        if not self.slug :
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Movie , self).save( *args , **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


LINK_CHOICES = (
    ('D' , 'DOWNLOAD LINK'),
    ('W' , 'WATCH LINK'),
)


class MovieLinks(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name='movie_watch_link', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=LINK_CHOICES , max_length=1)
    link = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.movie)
```

## Output :

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

## Full Output :

```
PS C:\Users\zenmy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\backup\imdb> python .\manage.py migrate  
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, movie, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying movie.0007_movie_created...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 381, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 230, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 410, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1546, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1524, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1403, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\zenmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1506, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Comment: I've tried checking the documentary aswell `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/`
and they said to set USE_TZ = True under settings.. I did, didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solutions here

[[u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406109/u-value-has-an-invalid-format-it-must-be-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-uuuuuu)

Everything under migrations had to be deleted and
`created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` had to be set to blank=True

Answer (score 0):

Just change the created field to
timezone.now is wrong replace it to timezone.now()

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

and after

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: `timezone.now` didn't have brackets, it had to be set to `(blank=True, default=timezone.now)`

Comment: Yoy can use datetime.datetime.now()